# Eslint (no-unused-expressions)

Tags: javascript, eslint

I'm using ternary expression for player change, and it works fine.
ESLint gives me this error - https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-expressions

```
activePlayer === 0 ? (activePlayer = 1) : (activePlayer = 0);
```

Could you help me make my code better?

Comment: `activePlayer = activePlayer === 0 ? 1 : 0`? Or just `activePlayer = !activePlayer`, and stop messing around with numbers.

Comment: *activePlayer* can be boolean?

Comment: You're using ternary operator as it it was an `if` conditional, which is kind of confusing. Also, it feels as if `activePlayer` should actually be a boolean variable rather than an integer (unless it's a multiplayer game and it actually represents a player number).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
activePlayer =  activePlayer === 0 ? 1 : 0 ;
```